# "Post" of the dependency injection in Azure Function has some strange problems

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am trying out the dependency injection for Azure Function.

I have the following super simple code block

```
    [FunctionName("CosmosWriteTest")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CosmosWriteTest([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        return new OkObjectResult("");
    }
```

As you can see, the type of this function is Post. I then copy the URL of this function from the console and paste it into the web browser. I received the "This localhost page can’t be found" error.

I tried to modify the type from post to get, or to "post, get", it works.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: oh shot, I just realized what's going on... I should use Postman like to make the post to that URL....

Comment: Yes, you can not make a post request from browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the http-triggered Function's description from official document:

> The HTTP trigger lets you **invoke a function with an HTTP request**. You
> can use an HTTP trigger to build serverless APIs and respond to
> webhooks.

You could run a function from an HTTP request (http trigger) and return an HTTP response from a function (http output) using Postman and curl, or access the url with the query string like this:
[image]

If you are using portal, you can also test it directly:
[image]